# What's more efficient? A number of SQL queries or looping through them all?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hopefully an easy one and more so to quell my interest on the matter as opposed to a proper problem.

I have a DB full of events and a time they happened at. I'm going to display how many total events happened on each day for the past five days. Now would it be better to do an SQL query for each day eg:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN beginningDay1 AND endDay1
$num = num_rows
SELECT * FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN beginningDay2 AND endDay2
$num2 = num_rows
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table
for each row
    case day 1
         day1Count++
    case day 2
         day2count++
```

Just keep in mind that the amount of events that could happen on one day could be anything.

Comment: Measure and it will tell you...

Comment: why don't you let the DBMS handle the counting? (count() and group by DATE(time))

Comment: @alex: Only if you have a large data set to use, because small ones (100K or less) are very likely to be the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will never scale like SQL does to count those rows. That's data that needs to be transferred over the wire, object(s) to hold the data & the operation(s) to count the day(s) when the database is specifically optimized for operations like this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.time BETWEEN beginningDay1 AND endDay1 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS num_day1,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.time BETWEEN beginningDay2 AND endDay2 THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS num_day2
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

There's no looping necessary in PHP.

Comment: As I mentioned on ysrb's answer, a single query looks good, though I don't quite understand how to use yours when getting the individual day counts from that query. =)

Comment: Ah, I understand now, definitely along the same lines as ysrb, just a slightly different method. Thanks. ^^

Answer (score 3):

The least DB calls the better. You can try:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN beginningDay1 AND endDay1) AS BDAY1,
 (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE time BETWEEN beginningDay2 AND endDay2) AS BDAY2
```

Comment: This is an interesting one, it may look a little messy but seems to accomplish all the counts in one query. Anyone have anything to day about this one compared to the others?

Comment: It works, but you should not scan/SELECT from the table more than you have to (in this case, once).  The [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) would give a more definitive answer to the performance question.

Answer (score 3):

It's normally faster if you leave selection, ordering and grouping to the database itself, that's what it's optimised for.

A query like:

```
select mydate, count(*) as quant from table
where mydate between '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-03'
group by mydate
```

should be sufficient. This will give you a table like:

```
mydate      quant
----------  -----
2011-01-01     42
2011-01-02     12
2011-01-03    197
```

and you just process the rows themselves.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest approach would be to do a single query that fetches all of the information you want and computes the counts grouped the way you want them, if possible.  So something along the lines of:

```
SELECT day, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY day;
```

Then in PHP you just loop the result-set and extract the counts.

Comment: There's no reason you can't count what you need in SQL, and leave PHP to handle presentation/display.

Comment: @OMG, isn't that what the answer says? The query has a groupby so I'm assuming that aroth's looping is the same as mine, just processing the one row per date resultset.

Comment: @OMG - What paxdiablo said.  His answer and mine are effectively the same.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Looping is still unnecessary.